# App pool with Sp services stops after few hours

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

- In my SP 2013 environment we have single SP server with SQL on same server.
- I have an app pool which has 14 applications under it which are are all SP services like reporting, performance point, metadata, user profile
- All services in central admin have full control for the app pool identity account
- Enable 32-Bit Applications is False for this app pool
- The app pool just stops after some time and needs to be manually restarted. After manually starting it fails again after say 10 hours
- The app pool identity pwd has not changed since 2012, there is another app pool where search service is running and it also runs under same identity and that runs without issues
- Could this be because of some heavy load? like 14 is too much on one App pool?
- There are some other issues on the server too, often Vs just in time debugger popup comes with message 'An unhandled .NET excelption occured in w3wp.exe.[9876]

Comment: Pull some info from the Application and System Event Logs. That is where any errors will be recorded.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Uninstall .net framework 4.0 then re-install it.
2. Create one service application in one application pool.
3. Check if the services are started in SharePoint. Go to central administration->system settings->manage services on server.